# Find the minimum value of n

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, maxima-minima

Find the minimum $natural$ value of $n$ for given expression 
$$(x+y) ^2=nxy$$
I know that intuitively that the value will be minimum at x=y, but i want the mathematical logic behind it. Please don't send by doing it by $$A.M.>=G.M.$$ because I already know that method. Thanks.

Comment: I guess $n$ is a natural number here

Comment: Yes the minimum value of n should be 4

Comment: I don't quite understand. Sure, if you use the inequality between the arithmetic and geometric mean you obtain that the minimum is $4$. What is wrong with this argument?

Comment: It is a perfectly reasonably argument I think Suman just wants to use calculus. You can find $4$ as a local minimum by taking both partial derivatives of the function $(x+y)^2/xy$ and setting equal to zero.

Comment: @GeorgeDewhirst, got it, thx. I should have noticed the tags.

Comment: I wanted it by calculus mainly. I would be very kind if anyone would send the answer. The inequalitity method is also good but i want a method by calculs or any other method.

Comment: Ok i will write it out

Comment: What values are $x$ and $y$ able to take? Natural, or real. If natural includes $0$, then $n=0$ seems to be the minimum.

Comment: Positive real numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $\frac{d}{dx}(x+y)^2/xy = [(xy)(2x+2y)-y(x+y)^2]/(xy)^2$ this is zero whenever $x=y$.

This is symmetric so it is the same story with the $y$ derivative. The value of the function at $x=y$ is $4$.

We can see this is a local minimum if we plot the graph. It is also clear that for the $(x,y)$ where this function is strictly positive, this is the minimum value the function takes.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help